¿Cómo hacer un bind para python de esta funcion C++?
Estoy intentando hacer un bind con pybind11 de una librería de C++ de la que solo tengo los header.
Estoy atascado con la definición de la siguiente función ```foo``:
struct reply {
   int code;
   bool ret;
};
struct input {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<unsigned char> auth;
};
class api {
public:
    static api* instance(struct anotherData);
}
reply foo(std::vector<input>& in);
};

El wrapper.cpp con pybind11 tiene:
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
PYBIND11_MODULE(bindexample, m) {
  pybind11::class_<reply>(m, "reply")
    .def(pybind11::init<>())
    .def_readwrite("code", &reply::code)
    .def_readwrite("ret", &reply::ret)

  pybind11::class_<input>(m, "input")
    .def(pybind11::init<>())
    .def_readwrite("name", &reply::name)
    .def_readwrite("auth", &reply::auth)

  pybind11::class_<api, std::unique_ptr<api, pybind11::nodelete>>(m, "api")
    .def_static("instance", static_cast<api* (*)(anotherData)>(&api::instance),
            pybind11::arg("anotherData"),
            pybind11::return_value_policy::reference)

    .def("foo", pybind11::overload_cast<input&>( &api::foo )) # Funcion sobrecargada 
}

Cuando intento compilar wrapper.cpp obtengo este error:
error: no match for call to ‘(const pybind11::detail::overload_cast_impl<input&>) (<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
             pybind11::overload_cast<input&>( &api::foo ) )

Tengo definidas sin error otras funciones donde los parametros que le paso son estructuras. Para esta funcion foo, ¿cómo debo pasar por parametro una referencia de un vector que contiene 'n' datos de tipo input?

pybind11::overload_cast<input&> claramente es para una función con un parámetro de tipo input&, no para un vector. Probaste con pybind11::overload_cast<std::vector<input>&>?

@Mateo gracias. Efectivamente con lo que comentas se resuelve. Pensaba que pybind resolvía esa conversion. Gracias de nuevo. Si quieres responde a la pregunta para dártela por válida

Recuerda que pybind11::overload_cast es equivalente a una conversión al tipo de un puntero de la función.
Tomando el ejemplo de la documentación:
py::class_<Pet>(m, "Pet")
   .def(py::init<const std::string &, int>())
   .def("set", static_cast<void (Pet::*)(int)>(&Pet::set), "Set the pet's age")
   .def("set", static_cast<void (Pet::*)(const std::string &)>(&Pet::set), "Set the pet's name");

Se puede simplificar así:
py::class_<Pet>(m, "Pet")
    .def("set", py::overload_cast<int>(&Pet::set), "Set the pet's age")
    .def("set", py::overload_cast<const std::string &>(&Pet::set), "Set the pet's name");

Así que si tu función tiene un solo parámetro de tipo std::vector<input>&, deberías utilizar:
pybind11::overload_cast<std::vector<input>&>(&api::foo)

